# How do I switch a page to a different domain using a userscript?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, redirect, userscripts, tampermonkey

I need to replace specific text, in a URL, using Greasemonkey.

For example, if the page is:

```
http://adf.st/?u=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com%2Fp%2F4XOVEaD5Ca%2F
```

Then the script will use the following URL:

```
http://adfa.cc/?u=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com%2Fp%2F4XOVEaD5Ca%2F
```

Note: The rest of the text after `adf.st/` is not fixed.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a standard-ish problem; use the pattern below.

The `@match` line is set to the old domain, and `newDomain` is set to the desired domain.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Redirect from one domain to another
// @match       *://adf.st/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var newDomain   = "adfa.cc";
var newURL      = location.protocol + "//"
                + newDomain                 //-- location.host
                + location.pathname
                + location.search
                + location.hash
                ;
/*-- replace() puts the good page in the history instead of the
    bad page.
*/
location.replace (newURL);
```

Comment: I have tried a lots of codes (more than 20 codes), none of them worked, but you are the rock. Its working withing second. Thank you very much. I am so much happy. You saved me a lots of time.